# Image src not being written to popup window body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need to print images using JavaScript. I couldn't find a jQuery solution to this, so I tried the following:

```
var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print Image', 'height=400,width=400');
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Image</title></head><body></body></html>');

var img = printWindow.document.createElement('image');
img.src = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51j68MN%2B99L._SL500_SS100_.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
};
printWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
printWindow.document.close();
```

Unfortunately, the popup HTML is this:

```
<html><head><title>Print Image</title></head><body><image></body></html>
```

So it appears that the `src` attribute isn't being set for the image.

I had previously put the image tag in the `document.write()` function, but I discovered the print window was blank for some images. My theory was that the print window was opening before some of the images finished downloading and thus showed (and printed) blank. So that's why I tried this method.

Why isn't this working, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: You are not appending img...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printWindow.document.createElement('img');
```

use correct tag name

look at http://jsbin.com/nurohutatasi/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var img = new Image();
```

instead of

```
var img = printWindow.document.createElement('image');
```

`<image>` isn't a correct image tag (`<img>` is it)

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the image before it is loaded. And also, closing the `printWindow` before the image load and print (the last two lines). `img` is the correct tag name:

```
var img = printWindow.document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51j68MN%2B99L._SL500_SS100_.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    printWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
};
//printWindow.document.body.appendChild(img);
//printWindow.document.close();
```